# longest matching prefix

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

In MySQL to match '12684041234' to the longest prefix you would do

```
SELECT num_prefix
FROM nums
WHERE '12684041234' LIKE CONCAT(num_prefix, '%')
AND LENGTH(num_prefix) = (
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(num_prefix))
    FROM nums
    WHERE '12684041234' LIKE CONCAT(num_prefix, '%')
)
```

Table `nums` has a column named `num_prefix` with prefix values.

How can I do it in hive ?

Comment: I think that your current SQL query is not the most efficient way to do it as it will require a full table scan. Is performance going to be an issue?

Comment: @Mark Byers: Performance is not an issue. It's a batch job, the table of the prefixes is not big (few hundreds) , and I can cache the results if I need to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT num_prefix FROM nums
  WHERE '12684041234' LIKE CONCAT(num_prefix,'%')
  ORDER BY num_prefix DESC
  LIMIT 1
;
```

This will give the longest prefix (`ORDER BY .. DESC`) and only one row (`LIMIT 1`).

Comment: This will give extremely poor performance. That condition can never use an index on num_prefix, therefore this query will always need a full table scan.

It's a little more effort but you can search for WHERE num_prefix IN (12684041234,1268404123,126840412,12684041,1268404,126840,12684,1268,126,12,1).

Comment: Although I haven't verified it myself, reportedly the query will be roughly 22x faster if you quote the numbers.

WHERE num_prefix IN ('12684041234','1268404123','126840412','12684041','1268404','126840','12684','1268','126','12','1')

Source: http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_lcr